# Django' login page

Tags: python, django, forms, e-commerce

I have imported all forms in my Django project and in my login page it says typeerror what could be the problem
Below is the error
"O 127.0.0.1:8000/login/ Apps ( HP Connected
T
ypeError at /login/ bool' object is not callable

```
Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ 
Django Version: 3.0.3 Exception Type: TypeError 
Exception Value: 'bool object is not callable 
Exception Location: C:\Users\USERPycharmProjects\KEONKEONIviews.py in login_page, 
line Python Executable: C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects KEON\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
Python Version: 3.7.0 
Python Path: response self.process_exception middleware(e, request)
```

Comment: You likely user `request.user.is_authenticated()`, but in the new versions of Django, it should be `request.user.is_authenticated` (so without brackets).

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you add the particular section of code that the exception references? What's at `Exception Location: C:\Users\USERPycharmProjects\KEONKEONIviews.py in login_page, 
line`